# Хранение обученной модели в памяти и обращение к ней из другого процесса python

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, машинное-обучение

Всем привет
Тестируем встроенную в SQL Server возможность запуска Python скриптов в целях машинного обучения

Все ок, кроме скорости. Документация Microsoft предлагает хранить обученную модель в таблице как код, полученный сериализацией модулем _pickle. И каждый раз при использовании модели этим же модулем десериализовывать.
pickle.loads занимает больше 2 секунд. Каждый запуск SQL процедуры запускает новый процесс python, потом закрывает его.

Как можно организовать хранение обученной модели в памяти?
На stackoverflow нашел рекомендацию развернуть приложение flask и хранить в ней десериализованные модели. Но как к ним обращаться из другого процесса python, понять не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если вы развернули приложение Flask, то по сути это веб сервер.

То есть для SQL сервера вы пишете скрипт, который через urllib (или подобный модуль) будет ходить на этот сервер, передавать туда данные через POST и получать требуемый ответ.

Ну если хочется извращений, можно навернуть то же самое на rabbitmq, очередях redis, pipe, да и любом возможном механизме IPC.

Comment: По сути веб-сервер мне как таковой не нужен.
Нужен просто процесс python, который постоянно висит и держит в памяти обученные модели.
А процессы, запускаемые SQL server, должны считывать эти модели.

про pipe читал, но правильно я понимаю, что один процесс должен запускать второй. только тогда они могут взаимодействовать?
остальные методы изучу, спасибо

Comment: У вас может быть один процесс с обученной моделью запущен сам по себе, а все остальные к нему обращаются тем или иным образом через IPC, в том числе через pipe. 

Pipe может быть именованным, то есть вы просто в процессе с моделью создаете его и ждете соединений. В процессах, порождаемых SQL server, открываете pipe с тем же именем и шлете туда данные.

Пример можно посмотреть вот тут: [Windows Python pipes](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes#Way_3:_Python_on_Windows)